# 10 years anniversary of Server Fault

Tags: discussion

Is there any plan for Server Fault's 10th year anniversary? The [first question](https://serverfault.com/q/1) posted on Server Fault on April 30, 2009.

Few months before Stack Overflow celebrated their 10th year Anniversary by creating the [anniversary page](https://stackoverflow.com/anniversary).

> [image: Server Fault Age]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! We want to celebrate the 10th anniversary of this community with you all.  Please [follow here for more information](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9492/we-want-to-celebrate-the-communitys-10th-anniversary-together).

Answer (score 3):

This is Amazing :)
I joined this site 7 Years ago, and my knowledge has increased extremely. 
I got my server administration skills improved tremendously. Cheers.