# We want to celebrate the community's 10th anniversary together!

Tags: discussion, anniversary

April 2019 marks the 10th anniversary of this great community and we want to celebrate together with you!

I am looking for suggestions from you as to how we can realistically enjoy this momentous occasion.  Do you have an idea for a contest? a race? a dance-off?  Let me know!

I want to also be able to offer prizes to the winners of the contest(s).  If you have ideas and suggestions on realistic items, please share as well.  If you're not sure, post it anyway. Let's have fun with this as we celebrate a decade of community work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [10 years anniversary of Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9488/10-years-anniversary-of-server-fault) :)

Comment: Not possible, it is. But this is where we can track people's suggestions rather than in comments or additional responses over there.

Comment: Holy crap. It's been ten years. I am _so_ old now... >sigh<

Comment: Just seen your edit, for the prize idea it could be a simple signed card by Joel Splosky with a small prepaid visa in example (like 10$)

Comment: or traveller mug with SF logo

Comment: @yagmoth555 I like the idea of the signed cards.  I'll have to track Joel first though....

Answer (score 6):

Almost all sysadmin like to keep some old stuff :P let's do a contest to make some art with some old server admin stuff, or find them a second life usage (and post a picture of the result)

In example;

- Using old travan/dds cartridge to make a pen holder.
- PIX501 used as book ends.
- ...

The winner could be the most upvoted's one.

Comment: Even though I've dumped most of my old old old stuff (e.g. my VAX 11/750 CPU boards), this would be too easy for me to win... Who else still has punch cards?  Or uses an IBM Model M 101 keyboard with the original PC/AT connector?

Comment: Obligatory "you kids today" comment: Travan and DDS aren't old... TK50 is old, or 9-track (I've still got a small one of those).   And did I mention my huge collection of thinwire BNC T connectors and termination resistors?

Comment: @Ward oh, you really beat me then ! I think I still have some BNC connectors, maybe one hidden somewhere, but I dont even know what is tk50, lol

Comment: Sorry, Ward, I use my old punch cards every day, as bookmarks, and I'm still trying to get some of my old email off 6250bpi half-inch tape reels.  My wife kindly let me hang my old Sun 3 motherboard on the wall, as art, until we redecorated our lounge last year.  It had jumpers to set mainboard memory; 1-32MB, if I recall!

Comment: I really like this idea and it would be a great way for people to see old things used in creative new ways!

Answer (score 6):

Legend has it that in the New York office, buried deep in a storage cupboard the location known only to the current NYC Operations Manager and the head of SRE, are the original Stack Overflow servers.

I'm not saying we should give them away, but I am saying we should do something with them. At least put them on display somewhere.

Comment: https://www.computerhistory.org/ would be the first place i'd try.

Comment: One of them would look good in my rack...

Comment: @MichaelHampton it wouldn't run well though. Unless you like particularly inefficient space heaters?

Comment: I'm actually looking for a space heater. So...

Comment: Beware of the Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea if we can send a prize to more than one person(s) !

We could thanks some members that helped the site grow and prosper and to make the site great.

**So to commemorate them it could be**;

- Select the top X contributor of all times, as they used to make the site great;
- Select the top X contributor of lately, like from 2018 or 2019;
- Select the top upvoted users from my other answer's contest; (To leave a chance to newcomer too)
- Select all former moderators. As they used to give a lot of their time to the site.

*Send a prize from there* :)

Comment: "Select all former moderators. As they used to give a lot of their time to the site." yep and I call dibs on all the good stuff

Comment: @MarkHenderson I'm not sure on the meaning of the expression used :P but none the less I wrote former, not 'current' for that purpose (to exclude myself) :-)

Comment: I was (only half) joking. I also am a former moderator, but as a now-employee I'm sure I am not eligible for any community rewards. Calling dibs means that I wanted first choice of all the rewards.

Comment: @MarkHenderson oh ok, lol, I got it :) thanks for the explanation

Comment: *"Select all former moderators."* - Good idea!!